# Form coming back with <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10e6ee898>

Tags: python, django

Disclaimer: I am fairly new to Django (trying to teach myself) and am currently trying to get a package that had little to no documentation https://github.com/byteweaver/django-coupons working for an app I am building.

I am trying to redeem a coupon I have created on the backend and I am getting some very strange errors. When I submit my form the `<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x10e6ee898>` that comes back in the form box and I am given a "This code is not valid" error. Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated as I have been beating my head against a wall with this for hours and hours now.

views.py

```
def gift_card(request):

user = request.user

if request.user.is_authenticated:
    edit_profile = EditProfileForm(user=user)
    redeem = CouponForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        edit_profile = EditProfileForm(request.POST, user=user)
        redeem = CouponForm(request.POST, user=user)
        if redeem.is_valid():
            Coupon.redeem(request.POST, user=user)
        else:
            edit_profile = EditProfileForm(user=user)
        return render(request, 'main/profile.html', {'edit_profile': edit_profile, 'redeem': redeem})

    return render(request, 'main/profile.html', {'edit_profile': edit_profile, 'redeem': redeem})
else:
    return redirect('/')
```

forms.py

```
class CouponForm(forms.Form):
code = forms.CharField(required=True,
                       label=_("code"),
                       widget=forms.TextInput
                       (attrs={'placeholder':_('Code'),
                               'class': 'text-center'}))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.user = None
    self.types = None
    if 'user' in kwargs:
        self.user = kwargs['user']
        del kwargs['user']
    if 'types' in kwargs:
        self.types = kwargs['types']
        del kwargs['types']
    super(CouponForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_code(self):
    code = self.cleaned_data['code']
    try:
        coupon = Coupon.objects.get(code=code)
    except Coupon.DoesNotExist:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code is not valid."))
    self.coupon = coupon

    if self.user is None and coupon.user_limit is not 1:
        # coupons with can be used only once can be used without tracking the user, otherwise there is no chance
        # of excluding an unknown user from multiple usages.
        raise forms.ValidationError(_(
            "The server must provide an user to this form to allow you to use this code. Maybe you need to sign in?"
        ))

    if coupon.is_redeemed:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code has already been used."))

    try:  # check if there is a user bound coupon existing
        user_coupon = coupon.users.get(user=self.user)
        if user_coupon.redeemed_at is not None:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code has already been used by your account."))
    except CouponUser.DoesNotExist:
        if coupon.user_limit is not 0:  # zero means no limit of user count
            # only user bound coupons left and you don't have one
            if coupon.user_limit is coupon.users.filter(user__isnull=False).count():
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code is not valid for your account."))
            if coupon.user_limit is coupon.users.filter(redeemed_at__isnull=False).count():  # all coupons redeemed
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code has already been used."))
    if self.types is not None and coupon.type not in self.types:
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code is not meant to be used here."))
    if coupon.expired():
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("This code is expired."))
    return code
```

models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Coupon(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField(_("Value"), help_text=_("Arbitrary coupon value"))
    code = models.CharField(
        _("Code"), max_length=30, unique=True, blank=True,
        help_text=_("Leaving this field empty will generate a random code."))
    type = models.CharField(_("Type"), max_length=20, choices=COUPON_TYPES)
    user_limit = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("User limit"), default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_("Created at"), auto_now_add=True)
    valid_until = models.DateTimeField(
        _("Valid until"), blank=True, null=True,
        help_text=_("Leave empty for coupons that never expire"))
    campaign = models.ForeignKey('Campaign', verbose_name=_("Campaign"), blank=True, null=True, related_name='coupons')

    objects = CouponManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_at']
        verbose_name = _("Coupon")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Coupons")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.code:
            self.code = Coupon.generate_code()
        super(Coupon, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def redeem(self, user=None):
        try:
            coupon_user = self.users.get(user=user)
        except CouponUser.DoesNotExist:
            try:  # silently fix unbouned or nulled coupon users
                coupon_user = self.users.get(user__isnull=True)
                coupon_user.user = user
            except CouponUser.DoesNotExist:
                coupon_user = CouponUser(coupon=self, user=user)
        coupon_user.redeemed_at = timezone.now()
        coupon_user.save()
        redeem_done.send(sender=self.__class__, coupon=self)
```

Update - Error on Coupon.redeem (see view for code):

```
'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'users'

in models.py | coupon_user = self.users.get(user=user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are creating `CouponForm` instance is not valid. You are doing

```
redeem = CouponForm({'code': Coupon.code}, user=user)
```

In this you are passing initial data for `code` as `Coupon.code` which is not correct. You should pass valid value for `code` ie. some text. But here you are passing `Coupon.code` with is attribute of `Coupon` model, not expected value.

---

As your form has `code` field, you can pass the `request.POST` to instantiate the form with submitted values.

```
redeem = CouponForm(request.POST, user=user)
```

Also, you are instantiating the form multiple times (e.g. in `if` and `else` part of `redeem.is_valid()` ), don't think you need this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The value I want to pass is the value the user enters on the form in the first place, can you give me any guidance as to how to do that? Would I use the `ugettext_lazy as _` functionality? Or is there a better way to go about that?

Comment: that seems to have worked as far as passing the right code to `CouponForm` however now I am running into an issue when trying to use the `Coupon.redeem` function to redeem the code. I have updated my question to reflect.

Comment: I went ahead and accepted your answer as you did indeed help me with the problem specified. Thank you very much! Now I just need to figure out how to update the code as redeemed.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the `Form` or `ModelForm` as a middle step, you shouldn't define its fields, only use the `Class Meta` and its `fields=` option for choosing the fields that are to be displayed.